# Rails 4 custom method to update an attribute on a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I've got the following link to publish a project:

```
# PATCH to a custom route called publish_project_path
= link_to 'Publish', publish_project_path(project), method: :patch

# in controller
def publish
  @project.publish   
  redirect_to projects_url, notice: 'Project was successfully published.'
end

# in model
def publish
  self.published = true
  self.save!
end  

# in routes
resources :projects do
  member do
    patch 'publish'
  end
end
```

Is this the generally accepted way of doing this sort of thing, where the attribute is set in the model, and not passed in through the params hash? Does my controller action even need to PATCH here?

Answer (score 1):

For me, this is how it should be. This is perfectly restful.

First of all, you defer the implementation of how a project should be published to the model. Second, you don't need to pass any form variables (like `params[:project][:published] # => true`) from the view through the controller to the model and update it in the `#publish` action. Less cause for mistakes.

And as for the right method: in Rails 3.x I would use `PUT` so yes, with Rails 4.x perhaps it is best to use `PATCH`.